# Using BERT for extracting Product Features

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, named-entity-recognition, bert-language-model

How can I use [BERT](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html) to extract **product features from text?**

For example, how to extract the ids from the next emails - WSK30015675, KTXFFC156, 4569TT11DRE

```
Hello John, Please order 15 dresses ID WSK30015675 from our storage. Thanks.

Hello Dan, this week we need to make sure we have KTXFFC156. And please make sure to order more of 4569TT11DRE. tnx :)
```

Notes:

- No regex
- The ids are unknown
- There is enough tagged data (emails >> ids)
- The ids are combinations of numbers and letter in different length

Comment: Please google for tutorials on BERT or post your attempt at implementing it and provide the error, or incorrect output alongside expected one. The question you ask it a very very generic one. Its like asking "Please tell me how to implement anomaly detection". Will request if you can be more specific.

Comment: look at this :https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-39442-4_21

Answer (score 1):

you need to detect which words are product features so you should use this archirecture

[image]

this architecture implemented in similar tasks like these:

https://gab41.lab41.org/how-to-fine-tune-bert-for-named-entity-recognition-2257b5e5ce7e

https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-with-bert-in-spark-nlp-874df20d1d77